# como dar espacios horizontales entre inputs con css?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

estaba usando `&nbsp;` para separar mis componentes y me funcionaba, pero aparte que ocupaba muchos, que no me gustaba mucho como se veía, en mi xhtml agregaron lo siguiente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="content">
        </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

y ya no los toma, sale el siguiente error

```html
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing  Error Traced[line: 320] Se hizo referencia a la entidad "nbsp", pero no se declaró.
```

entonces tengo todo amontonado, como puedo dar esos espacios con css?
estoy usando primefaces

Answer (score 1):

Los espacios los puedes dar, **usando márgenes** (espaciado entre elementos) o **paddings** (espaciado entre el contenedor y su contenido):

Puedes usarlo poniendo una clase a esos elementos así:

```
.clase-elegida{
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  /*O usando los padding*/
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Puedes usar además el acortador, teniendo en cuenta el sentido de las agujas del relog (arriba, derecha, abajo, izquierda), el proximo ejemplo es lo mismo que arriba:

```
.clase-elegida2{
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Y de hecho los puedes acortar más, ya que si usas solo dos, es decir, así `(0 10px)`: significa (arriba,abajo derecha, izquierda). Ejemplo:

```
<!--En el HTML-->
<nav class="elemento"></nav>
```

```
/*En el CSS*/
.elemento { margin: 0 10px; }
```

---

También puedes generar clases dinámicas que vas añadiendo a los elementos cada vez que los necesites así:

```
.ml_10px { margin-left: 10px}
.mr_15px { margin-right: 15px}
```

Y en html:

```
<div class="ml-10px"></div>
<div class="mr-15px"></div>
```

La desventaja es que tienes que crear clases independientes para cada lado o medida, sirve mucho para clases dinámicas, que vas colocando dinamicamente cuando pintas varios elementos al tiempo, es el modelo *"bootstrap"* pero es algo engorroso cuando pintas manualmente cada elemento independientemente.

---

Lo otro es que lo agregues a cada elemento html, usando estilos en linea:

```
<section style="margin-left: 10px">
```

Pero no es una opción que te recomiende solo en casos excepcionales o de no más alternativa, ya que el código de esta manera es mucho más difícil de mantener y tienes que estar repitiendo el código en cada elemento de manera innecesaria.